# Product page sometimes displays 404/links to home

Tags: magento-1.9.2.1, http-error-404

I'm running 1.9.2.1 with the latest security patches installed. When visiting a product page, sometimes (1 in 100 or something?) it displays a 404 error. When refreshing the page, it'll display correctly. Even less often it just links to the homepage. When navigating back to the catalog and clicking the product again, it works correctly.

I can't reproduce the problem and there's nothing special in the logs as well. Any advice how to debug this problem? Thanks!